# check state of another statechart agent type Anylogic

Tags: types, communication, anylogic, agent, statechart

I am in the statechart of the one agent type (Person) and I want to send a message to another agent type (Person2) in a certain state (atHome), but when I use code below the program throws me an error

```
for( Person2 m : main.person2s ) {

   if( m.inState(atHome)==true ) { 
       send("hi", m);
   }
}
```

what should I do to call another agent type in a certain state?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: `Exception during discrete event execution:
class prueba6.Person2 cannot be cast to class prueba6.Person (prueba6.Person2 and prueba6.Person are in unnamed module of loader 'app')                               at prueba6.Person$personStatechart_state.getStatechart(Person.java:1)
at com.anylogic.engine.IStatechartState.inState(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.engine.Agent.inState(Unknown Source)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead

```
for( Person2 m : main.person2s ) {

   if( m.inState(m.atHome) ) { 
       send("hi", m);
   }
}
```